# Vuejs how to display laravel input array validation errors

Tags: validation, vue.js, laravel-5

I am having trouble showing error messages in my vue component that are retrieved my my Laravel app.

This is the response in the network tab

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {results.0.winner: ["This field is required"], results.1.winner: ["This field is required"],…}
results.0.winner: ["This field is required"]
results.1.winner: ["This field is required"]
results.2.winner: ["This field is required"]
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

And this is the error in console

> admin.js:59648 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read
>   property '0' of undefined"

This is my component

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div v-for="(setting, index) in settings">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="setting.number">
                            <div v-if="errors && errors.results[index].winner" class="text-danger">{{ errors.results[index].winner }}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save Results
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    props: {
        settings: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        },
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            errors: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        submit: function() {
            let results = [];

            this.settings.forEach(function(item) {
                results.push({
                    prize: item.prize,
                    winner: item.number
                });
            });

            axios.post('save', {results: results}).then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200) {
                    //window.location.href = '/admin/lottery'
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                     this.errors = error.response.data.errors || {}
                }
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

and if it helps my laravel function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'results.*.winner'  => 'required|gt:0',
    ],
    [
        'results.*.winner.required' => 'This field is required',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The index key that you have using on

```
errors.results[index].winner
```

It belongs to iterable variable settings, although you think you are sure that intersection match, this is not recommended, and I think that here is "error in render".

You have to code:

```
<div v-for="(result, index) in errors.results">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="setting.number">
                <div class="text-danger">{{ result.winner }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div v-for="(setting, index) in settings">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="setting.number">
                <div v-if="errors && errors.results[index].winner" class="text-danger">{{ errors.results[index].winner }}</div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there are no errors. Will this still render?

Comment: My approaches define render errors in different list.
If you want render error below inputs (along with each field), one solucionts would be, in the catch of axios, call new function, and here, check index error and if exist add value to new property settings[index].error, in this way, you make sure that setting.error exist.